# Python 3 version outdated on Mint 20.1

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, python3

I am having a course with Python 3 and I see its 3.8.5:

```
mint@mint-System-Product-Name:~$ python3 --version 
Python 3.8.5
```

I've updated the OS to the latest version possible, using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get full-upgrade -y
```

Also the GUI updater does not show any new updates, however, Python is outdated.

I've even downloaded the latest version and installed it with the help of this page:

https://brightwhiz.com/install-python-3-9-ubuntu/

Can you please help me? I need Python 3.9. Thank you!

Comment: What feature of python 3.9 do you need? Version 3.8.5 is not that old, are you sure you really _need_ a new one? Also, if you have already downloaded and installed a newer version, what is the problem? Does it not work?

Comment: Whatever you do, do not change default python, system requires that for many internal uses and if you remove it, you break your install. But you can install other versions of python if desired and just have to specify that version when running commands.

Comment: I wanted to have the latest version of Python to avoid having deprecated code in the future. 
I usually work with the most stable and recent versions of OS, IDE, and programming language version. I am not missing anything in particular, not now, but in the future I may need to do changes, which could be avoided by simply having the most recent Python. If I could just use Python 3.9 for the project in PyCharm, that would be fine, but 3.9 does not appear in the list of base interpreters in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build python3.9, it is available on Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa, it can be installed through `apt` from Mint repositories:

```
$ apt policy  python3.9

python3.9:
  Installed: 3.9.0-5~20.04
  Candidate: 3.9.0-5~20.04
  Version table:
 *** 3.9.0-5~20.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The installation instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.9 200
```

Making `python3` pointe to `3.9`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python /usr/bin/python3.8 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python /usr/bin/python3.9 200
```